# Index Out Of Bounds Exception in ArrayList while removing objects

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception, jcreator

Platform: JCreator

I usually use for loops that count from the back because theoretically when removing they should collapse fine:

```
0123456789
```

removing even numbers:

```
i = 9: 0123456789
i = 8 //remove 8: 012345679
i = 7: 012345679
i = 6 //remove 6: 01234579
```

and so on

But I get this exception when the object is removed:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3

```
for (int i = dArea.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (dArea.get(i).getOwn() == 1) {
        if (dArea.get(i).getSK() == 2) {
            if (dArea.get(i).getX() - dArea.get(i).getW() / 2 > 1350) {
                dArea.remove(i);
            }
            if (dArea.get(i).getX() + dArea.get(i).getW() / 2 < 0) {
                dArea.remove(i);
            }
            if (dArea.get(i).getY() - dArea.get(i).getH() / 2 > 685) {
                dArea.remove(i);
            }
            if (dArea.get(i).getY() + dArea.get(i).getH() / 2 < 0) {
                dArea.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why and how to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `else if` instead of `if`.

Otherwise one iteration in your loop may delete more than one element (once for the 'w' check and once for the 'h' check).